# Using texture image with alpha makes mesh 'see through'

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, texture-mapping

I am rendering an obj file in OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android with Back-Culling enabled. Only some part (the necklace around the neck) of the texture image actually has alpha.

When rendering only the mesh, it looks fine :

[image]

However, on enabling the texture, I am able to see through the mesh onto the other side. You can see below that the right hand which is behind the body also becomes visible. Any ideas what might be going wrong ?

[image]

Edit:

I have tried the following :

1. Enabling/Disabling back face culling
2. Checking the ordering of vertices
3. Checking if normals are inside at some points

But nothing seem to work. Any other direction would be appreciated.

Edit 2 :

I opened up the texture image and filled all the transparent area with black color by saving it as no alpha layer in a image editing program. And this is how it looks now :

[image]

Transparency issue is gone, but then I won't be able to see the necklace properly.

Edit 3 : Can [Alpha-blending and the Z-buffer](https://sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/alpha_sorting.html) be an issue as described in the link ? It claims 'The Z buffer doesn't work for transparent polygons.'

Comment: This seems to be a serious issue. If you are using a simulator it might be the cause, try it on a device. Since you suddenly have a transparency the depth test will work a bit different since the object behind a transparent object must still be drawn so you may partially see it. It is possible that your blend function is somehow strange and causes this as well.

Comment: @MaticOblak I am on the device itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few solutions for the conflict of the depth buffer and alpha blending.

In your case it might be best to simply disable the blending and discard the pixels in the fragment shader.

You probably just have some semitransparent pixels on the borders of the accessory the rest is either `1.0` or `0.0`. So maybe a pass such as if `alpha < 0.5` discard else set alpha to `1.0`.

Another way would simply make sure that those blended objects are drawn last. If you have only one of such objects on the scene it should work. But if you have multiple one behind the other you may again encounter issues.

Comment: You really think this could be the issue or you are suggesting me to follow this solution in case this is actually the issue ?

Comment: There is no way to be 100% sure but you can analyze the result you are seeing. The model works fine without transparent pixels. As soon as you add transparency you can see not only that the part with transparency is wrong but the whole model is drawn incorrectly. What you are seeing is a fail in depth test. All those extra polygons are drawn correctly but do not respect that something is drawn before them. Note that even the legs are wrong. I assume that the drawing is the same as if you would completely disable the depth buffer. You may actually try to do that and compare it with your result.