# OpenGL - ES drawing and blending

Tags: opengl-es

I'm developing program that is described below.
I draw two triangles with different depths.
For below example, I'd like to split green triangle to visible part and hidden part. Then, finally using blending function, the hidden part of the green triangle is colored as transparent, and visible part is colored as original color.

[image: example]

Now, I write codes using opengl-ES (with JNI).
And, I have two questions.

First :

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(gProgram);
glGetUniformLocation(gProgram, "vColor");


const GLfloat gTriangleVertices1[] =
{
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
};
float color1[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
const GLfloat gTriangleVertices2[] =
{
    -0.7f, 0.0f, 0.3f,
    0.5f, 0.3f, 0.3f,
    0.5f, 0.0f, 0.3f,
};
float color2[] = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};



int mColorHandle1;
int mColorHandle2;

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearDepthf(1.0f);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
glUniform4f(mColorHandle1, color1[0], color1[1], color1[2], color1[3]);
glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, gTriangleVertices1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);
//glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glUniform4f(mColorHandle2, color2[0], color2[1], color2[2], color2[3]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
```

from this code, if I change glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER) to glDepthFunc(GL_LESS), the result shows visible and hidden part correctly.
However, I do not understand why it shows correct answer.
Because, I added vertex gTriangleVertices1, but I do not add gTriangleVertices2.
**Even thou I do not add vertices of triangle 2, It gives me correct answer. why?**

Second question, I think it is correct to use blending function (I checked it works on glut / freeglut). but why it doesn't work on gl-es.

```
///////////////////////// visible part ///////////////////////// 
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearDepthf(1.0f);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
glUniform4f(mColorHandle1, color1[0], color1[1], color1[2], color1[3]);
glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, gTriangleVertices1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glUniform4f(mColorHandle2, color2[0], color2[1], color2[2], color2[3]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // same to initialize depth func
///////////////////////// visible part ///////////////////////// 


///////////////////////// hidden part ///////////////////////// 
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearDepthf(1.0f);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
glUniform4f(mColorHandle1, color1[0], color1[1], color1[2], color1[3]);
glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, gTriangleVertices1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glUniform4f(mColorHandle2, color2[0], color2[1], color2[2], 0.5f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
///////////////////////// hidden part /////////////////////////
```

I just added blending function. If I uses visible/hidden part alone, it gives correct result. However if I use blending function, it gives strange result as shown below : it gives transparent hidden green triangle.
what's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The first question:**

You created a major bug by saying `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 3);` as this produces an overflow on your buffer. The result of it is unexpected but in your case your compiler seems to have decided that the two arrays you defined are tightly packed:

```
const GLfloat gTriangleVertices1[] =
{
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
};
const GLfloat gTriangleVertices2[] =
{
    -0.7f, 0.0f, 0.3f,
    0.5f, 0.3f, 0.3f,
    0.5f, 0.0f, 0.3f,
};
```

And are considered as

```
const GLfloat gTriangleVertices[] =
{
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    -0.7f, 0.0f, 0.3f,
    0.5f, 0.3f, 0.3f,
    0.5f, 0.0f, 0.3f,
};
```

So the overflow actually jumps to the part of the memory where the second vertex data is. Make no mistake of thinking what you did is correct by mistake. It is not correct and this can break on different version or for any other reason, platform, device... So fix it.

**The second question:**

The blending and depth buffer do not go together. You need to avoid this combination. I will not explain the reasons here (search a bit for it) but the result is undefined and you may not use that. Use one or the other.

If you will search the web on how to tackle this you will not find a correct answer for your situation though as it is very unique. What I suggest for the general solution for your case is to add a stencil buffer.

The first call should also draw to the stencil buffer which is then used to draw in the last call as well. So the last call should have a depth test disabled but stencil enabled. But doing that you should most likely simply remove the depth and use stencil only.

I am sure there are other possible solutions to this by using an alpha channel as well but in any case remember that depth buffer combined with blending is strictly forbidden and the behavior is undefined. It means it can even vary between the GPUs.

Comment: Why would using blending and depth testing have a different outcome on different GPUs? If you draw something translucent and another translucent object in front of it, then there's no problem, if you draw it behind it, then depth testinf kicks in.

Comment: @Bálint I thought that as well but then I saw some results that seem to completely destroy the depth buffer. Check the results in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893742/using-texture-image-with-alpha-makes-mesh-see-through/35912027#35912027